# WinHttpGetDefaultProxyConfiguration returns wrong Proxy Info

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to retrieve default proxy settings. To do this I use next code:

```
WINHTTP_PROXY_INFO ProxyInfo;
ZeroMemory( &ProxyInfo, sizeof(ProxyInfo) );

BOOL result = WinHttpGetDefaultProxyConfiguration(&ProxyInfo);

if (result)
{
    //...
}
```

The function returns TRUE, but in ProxyInfo I have: `WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_NO_PROXY` and `lpszProxy == NULL` no matter what settings I put via ProxyCfg.exe->Connections->LAN Settings->Proxy Server. Do you know what I'm doing wrong here?

I tested this code on Win7 64bits machine, but I need it to work in all WinXP+ versions.

I checked libproxy project and there proxy settings are retrieved from registries. Is this method reliable? Is the same registry path for proxy configuration in all Windows versions?

Comment: Why don't you use WinHttpGetDefaultProxyConfiguration, and, if you see bogus results, read it from registry? "in all Windows versions" is full of optimism - prepare to use multiple methods.

Comment: @ActiveTrayPrntrTagDataStrDrvr But how can I know if the result is wrong?:) On my computer I know this because I can check the registry/ProxyCfg.exe and see the result is not correct. On other computer how can I do this?

Comment: I'd go with registry over anything. If the registry method retrieves no proxy, I'd try WinHttp. Other than that, grabbing and setting multiple proxies from all sources is also an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried the method used in Chrome and it works fine. Also it should be tested in multiple Windows versions.

```
WINHTTP_CURRENT_USER_IE_PROXY_CONFIG ProxyInfo;
BOOL result = WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser(&ProxyInfo);
```